# Display Datetime in X axis - Plotly

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, plotly, plotly.js

I am working on MEAN Application. I am trying to display some values on Y axis and datetime in X axis with time interval of 3 hours (i.e) 12 AM,3 AM,6 AM,9 AM,12 PM,3 PM.....

My Y-axis code goes like this.

```
   yaxis: {
            tickmode:"array",
            tickvals:[0,0.5,1.5,4,8,16],
            ticktext:[0,0.5,1.5,4,8,16],
            showgrid: false,
            showline: true,
            autoscale: true,
            autorange: true,
            fixedrange: true,
            ticks: 'outside',
            zeroline: false
          },
    xaxis: {
        showgrid: false,
        showline: true,
        ticks: 'outside',
        zeroline: false
        }
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `datetime` array with `3h` intervals for `xaxis` value.

```
//make a date-time array with a interval    
function makeRange(y,interval) { 
      //y is yaxis data
      //interval is a numeric value for hour
      var x = []; //date array
      var d = new Date();
      for(i=0; i<y.length; i++){
         d.setHours(i*interval,0,0) //Add hour interval in date time
         var hours = d.getHours(); //get hours
         var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'; //set am/pm 
         var date = d.getDate()  + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getFullYear() + " " + hours + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ampm; //create date format
         x.push(date)
      }
    return x;
  }
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/mdnasirfardoush/pen/djMjzO?editors=0010)